# Any way to get tooltip-like temporary information displayed close to the mouse pointer after operations?

Tags: interface, selection-tools

For instance, at least at my current (rather beginner) level of Blender skills, I think it would be quite useful to show the number of selected vertices, edges and faces after selecting or de-selecting such. Yes, I know you can see it in the "Statistics" overlay and in the Status Bar, but those are both far away from your centre of attention, and turning your gaze to them to confirm that you have selected exactly what you think you have is a bit disruptive.

Let me add that I am a programmer so I am open to doing some Python scripting if necessary to achieve this, if it is in theory possible. Or, if I get good code pointers, I could even add some missing simple functionality to the C++ code.

Comment: for me the statistics overlay is working pretty well. i can understand that the status bar is a bit far away but the overlay makes a good job - i think.

Comment: Sure, it works, but still, on a large display (27" or larger), if you are keeping your attention focused on the middle of the screen where you are manipulating a mesh, having to look away towards the top-left corner to verify that you indeed have the number of vertices selected that you think, is sometimes a bit distracting. At least to me. Some kind of immediately visible feedback right where you are working (i.e. where the mouse pointer is) would be nice.